# String to four integers (not an array)

Tags: ruby

I've got a string like so: `"1,2,3,4"`. I want to output it to four integers like `1, 2, 3, 4`, not an array. How do I achieve that?

This returns an array and is no good:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use Ruby's array unpacking syntax.

```
i1, i2, i3, i4 = "1,2,3,4".split(',').map(&:to_i)
puts i1 #=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',').map(&:to_i).join(', ')
```

or

```
"1,2,3,4".gsub(',', ', ')
```

to output the format as you wish it.